# Have HTML Div Act as an Iframe, But Using Children as Content

Tags: html, css, iframe

Is it possible to have an HTML5 `<div>` (or any other element) act like it is an iframe, but with the content loaded from it's children instead of from an URL? For example, if you were to have this setup in your main document:

```
<iframe style='margin-left:50px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;' src='foo.html'></iframe>
```

And the content of `foo.html` were:

```
<div style='position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:black;'></div>
```

The main document would appear to show a black square, of about 250px width and height, with a 300px or so margin to the left. If a script in `foo.html` were to change the sizing or positioning of the square, the sizing and positioning of the square would change within the iframe, instead of within the main document as a whole.

What I'm interested in doing is something more like this:

```
<magicalframe style='margin-left:50px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;'>
    <div style='position:fixed;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        width:50%;
        height:50%;
        background-color:black;'></div>
</magicalframe>
```

Where `<magicalframe>` acts like an iframe, but takes content from within itself, instead of from the URL. Fundamentally, I want the *content* of the `<magicalframe>` to center and size itself as if the `<magicalframe>` were its body, instead of doing it using the body or window as a whole.

I'm guessing there's a very simple solution to this. Am I correct?

Comment: You can load any dynamic content into a div (or any other dom element) that you want. But if it's a `<div>`, then it's still part of the containing document, and subject to all of its css/js. That's why there's iframes. It lets you load a completely independent document into a portion of the "screen", with its own css, js, etc... You can NOT have that separation with your magicalframe.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('magicalframeid'),
    iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframedoc.body.innerHTML = 'your manual div contents';
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand what you want, seems like you could probably just put

```
transformX: 0;
```

on the parent.

untried, but from MDN on position:fixed: 'Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page. This value always create a new stacking context. When an ancestor has the transform property set to something different than none then this ancestor is used as container instead of the viewport'

But it also seems like you'd get the exact same functionality out of a parent with:

```
position: relative;
```

and a child with

```
position: absolute;
```

Unless you plan on scrolling within the parent.

EDIT: Either way, you probably want

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the parent as well.